# Supprimer vs fermer vs clôturer

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

When a user requests to close his online account which will result in all the user's data being removed/deleted (account can no longer be re-activated after), what's the best French verb that resembles this? *Supprimer*, *fermer* or *clôturer*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a French, I think that "**supprimer**" is the best word for this situation because the account is completely removed, with its user data. 
The word "**fermer**" can be used too, but I think it can be confusing if you say "Je ferme mon compte" because sometimes you could understand that you close your account without being sure that the data is removed. Notice that if your account is closed by the administrator of the website, you would more likely use "Mon compte a été fermé" because you haven't decided to close your account.
The word "**clôturer**" is, like @Alone-zee mentionned, when you close a bank account.

Example:

> J'ai **supprimé** mon compte.

In this situation, I am sure that my account has been deleted.

> Mon compte a été **fermé** par les administrateurs du site.

In this situation, my account has been closed by the websites administrators.

> J'ai **fermé** mon compte.

It can also be used in the case that the user closed his account, but it is not used very often.

> J'ai **clôturé** mon compte.

It is used when you close a bank account.

If you want to close you account temporarily, or if it has been shutdown temporarily by the administrators, you would use the word **désactivé**

> Mon compte a été **désactivé** par les administrateurs

Answer (score 2):

When an online account is closed for good, "fermé" is the most appropriate word; "supprimé" (albeit not entirely wrong) is usually more about a video being removed, deleted. "Clôturer" is used more formally (as an antonym of "ouvrir") when you close, for instance, a bank account.

A YouTuber explaining the reason for the closure of his account:

« [Pourquoi cette chaîne est-elle fermée ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_plIkctxXcI) »

---

"Fermé" conveys the idea of an account being closed permanently:

> Le compte Twitter de Donald Trump a été **fermé**.

With "supprimé / coupé / désactivé", on the other hand, an account may be closed only temporarily (accidentally or otherwise), with "désactivé" especially emphasising this temporary nature:

> {vs}: Le compte Twitter de Donald Trump a été **supprimé** / **coupé** / **désactivé**.

Comment: *Supprimé* would be even more drastic than *fermé*. It would mean that the content isn't accessible anymore and possibly that all the data has been erased. Also I wouldn't use *coupé* for an account.

Comment: *Suspendu* too for a temporary state.